# Why was the stone moved from Gringotts?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

Is there any info that could explain why the Sorcerer's/Philosopher's Stone was moved from Gringotts to Hogwarts?  My guess would be "Dumbledore's intuition" but I don't recall anything that would explain why the stone was moved when it was.  Did Dumbledore know Voldemort was trying to get the stone?  If this is the case how did he know and why did he only move it at the beginning of the first book and not some time before that?

Answer (score 11):

Considering how soon after the move Quirrell's break-in happened, I would guess that something Quirrell did to prepare for the break-in came to Dumbledore's attention, and he decided to make sure the stone wasn't there when it happened. I don't know of any direct canon evidence for this, though.

Answer (score 5):

No canon info I'm aware of, BUT:

- Dumbledore suspected Quirrell was up to no good (in DH we see Snape's memories where he'd told by Dumbledore to "keep an eye on Quirrell for me"). This means he may have been aware Voldemort was on the move.
- This was the year Harry would have ventured forth from Privet Drive's protection to the Wizarding World, and become widely seen. Dumbledore may have suspected that this would draw Voldemort out, and once drawn out he'd want to use the stone.

Comment: Good call on the DH reference.  My only issue with that is that it's clear from context that in that quote Harry is already at school so we don't get direct evidence that Dumbledore was suspicious of Quirrell before the break-in.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that Dumbledore had been planning on hiding the stone in the mirror of Erised, which is explained at the end of the movie.  Dumbledore also tells Harry during the movie that the mirror will be moved to a safer location, which I take to mean safer yet for the stone - both for where it is located and how to get the stone.

Comment: But why move it when they did?  Voldemort had been gone for around 11 years at that point.  What was the motivation for moving the stone from Gringott's (the safest place in the world to store something besides Hogwarts apparently) to Hogwarts?

Comment: In the later books, Dumbledore explains to Harry that he has long expected Voldemort to somehow return. He was probably being prudent and denying one possible means of said return.

Comment: But my question is that if he long suspected it... why wait until he did to move the stone to Hogwarts?  He apparently felt it was safe at Gringotts up until the first book.  What changed that made him move the stone?